# COUNTIFS function in Google Data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have 2 columns called continent and completion and i would like to calculate completion %  for each continent based on below data.
This was defined in excel using COUNTIFS() function

Can we achieve this In data studio??

Completion % formula is Total number of  Status in 'closed' / Total number of Status
Status values are  'open','in progress','service completed','closed'

```
continent          completion %         

------------     -------------------       

Asia                  97%(used countifs function to calculate percentage in excel)
Europe                89%              
North America         93%
```

Answer (score 21):

From what I understand you will need a new field called 'Closed' and that code should look something like:

```
CASE 
   WHEN [Whatever your status field name is] = 'closed' THEN 1
   ELSE 0
END
```

And then you will have to utilize that in another new field called 'Total closed' that should look like:

```
SUM(CASE 
      WHEN Closed = 1 THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END)
```

And then from there you can create 'Completion %':

```
Total closed / COUNT([Your status field])
```

[Here is a link](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/CountIf-Formula/td-p/1144299) to a google forum question that might be useful