# DataStudio SUM text fields if contains " utm_source = 'google' " [close]

Tags: looker-studio

I'm using BigQuery data in DataStudio and I need a total of how many entries of `utm_medium` is equal to "google"

I have `utm_medium` value in my BQ as string

```
CONTAINS_TEXT(utm_medium, "google")
```

Is giving me all entries and I just need the total count of utm_medium = 'google'

[image]

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425437/countifs-function-in-google-data-studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula returns `True`/`False` values.  If you just count them, the number of `True`/`False` values, the result will be the number of non-null values (or the record count if all records are non-null).

To solve this problem, you need to convert `True` values to 1 (one), and `False` values to 0 (zero).  As in:

```
CASE
  WHEN CONTAINS_TEXT(utm_medium, 'google') THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Since the result of this formula is numeric (0 or 1), you can sum these numbers (instead of count).  The result should be what you expect.

Comment: Thank you very much @Diego Queiroz. I need also to make a multiplication with this value, It is possible to do in the same formula?

Comment: If you need to calculate values based on this field, you need to turn it a metric. Just surround the formula with `SUM` function and do your multiplication, as in `SUM(CASE ... END)*20`. Obviously, you can only do multiplications over constants or over aggregated fields (SUM, COUNT, AVERAGE, etc). It doesn't make sense to multiply a metric with a field.